# Do I need to add properties to make the desired output?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got 1 of three of my desired outputs (the second test) but can't figure out how to get the other two. I've included test code below also.

```js
function car(gas, mpg) {
  this.gas = gas;
  if (this.gas <= 0) {
    this.empty = true;
  }
  this.mpg = mpg;
  //this.range = gas * mpg;
  //this.empty = empty;

  this.drive = function(miles) {
    this.gas -= miles / this.mpg;
    if (this.gas <= 0) {
      this.empty = true;
    }
  };

  this.fill = function(gallons) {
    if (this.gas <= 0) {
      this.fill = false;
    }
  };
}
//test code

var test = new car(15, 30);
console.log(test.empty); //expected output = false

test.drive(500);
console.log(test.empty); //expected output = true

test.fill(20);
console.log(test.empty); //expected output = false
```

Comment: There are no arrays in that code.

Comment: I've moved your code into a *runnable* Stack Snippet, and swapped `console.log` for `alert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than anything else, programming is about paying close attention to logic and details.

You're not going to get `false` for `empty` if you never set `empty` to `false`, so your first `console.log` doesn't work because you've never set `empty` to anything.

Your second `console.log` does show `true` because `drive` sets it `true` correctly for the `this.gas <= 0` condition.

Your third doesn't because (this is where details come in) you're setting the property `fill`, not `empty`.

Since `empty` is just a reflection of the state of `gas`, you could consider using a *getter* so you don't have to manage `empty` at all. In `car`:

```
Object.defineProperty(this, "empty", {
    get: function() {
        return this.gas <= 0;
    }
});
```

Also, `gas` should never be allowed to be negative, so you probably want `drive` to do this:

```
this.gas = Math.max(0, this.gas - miles/this.mpg);
```

...which sets `this.gas` to `0` if you're trying to drive too far. You might consider having `drive` calculate how far you actually went before running out of gas and returning that, so the caller knows you didn't actually drive as far as requested...

---

Side note: The *overwhelming* convention in JavaScript is that constructor functions like your `car` start with a capital letter: `Car`.

Comment: Thanks so much this helps allot!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing with else statement.

```
 function car(gas, mpg) {
    this.gas = gas;
    if (this.gas <= 0){this.empty = true;}
    else{this.empty = false;}
    this.mpg = mpg;
    //this.range = gas * mpg;
    //this.empty = empty;

    this.drive = function (miles) {
    this.gas -= miles/this.mpg;
    if(this.gas <=0) {
    this.empty = true;
    }else{
     this.empty = false;
     }
    };

    this.fill = function (gallons){
    if (this.gas <=0) {
    this.fill = false;}
    else{this.fill = true;}
    };
    }
```

Comment: Rather than `if (condition) { value = true; } else { value = false; }`, just use `value = condition;`